# What is the difference between custom element and just an import using require in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

In the skeleton-nav app.html, the nav-bar is imported like a custom element using the require statement and can by used like a custom element using tags , but according to the docs you also need to define it by importing customelement or by using CustomElement convention.  However, the nav-bar.js does not use customelement or the convention but you can still use it as a custom tag in your html.  What is the difference between the nav-bar template and one defined using the customelement syntax.  By using require on any template does this mean that it is automatically a custom element, is this another convention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the documentation is simply not up to date. Because in previous version i indeed needed to use the convention but as you said it is not necessary anymore. Just a camelcase name should be enough fir any custom element. But you still need the convention for the custom attribute I believe.